# javaでif文について

Tags: java, netbeans

現在NetBeansでjavaの勉強をしているのですが

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("判定　");
int x = sc.nextInt();

if(x >= 0.4)
            System.out.println("判定　Ａ");
else if(x >= 0.3 && x < 0.4)
            System.out.println("判定　Ｂ");
else
            System.out.println("判定　Ｃ");
```

と打って実行した際
1や0だとしっかりと実行してくれるのですが
0.5や0.2などで打ったらエラーになってしまいます。
原因解明よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `double x = sc.nextDouble():` ではだめなのでしょうか?

Comment: 質問のタイトルで小数を利用したいことを明確にすると質問内容に即したものになると思いました。

Answer (score 1):

int 型で表現できる値は 1 や 0 などの整数です。
0.5 や 0.2 といった小数を表現するには、double 型（または float 型）を使用する必要があります。

質問のコードの場合は `int x = sc.nextInt();` ではなく、 `double x = sc.nextDouble();` とすれば動きます。

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("判定　");
double x = sc.nextDouble();

if(x >= 0.4)
            System.out.println("判定　Ａ");
else if(x >= 0.3 && x < 0.4)
            System.out.println("判定　Ｂ");
else
            System.out.println("判定　Ｃ");
```

Comment: please use      double x = sc.nextDouble();